# How to measure and reduce your memory use in Jhipster app? when booting with Heroku

Tags: heroku, jvm, jhipster

I can not make my app to boot in Heroku (using hobby plan, Jhipster 5.7 ) because I'm using too much memory as Help Service says:

```
Your app is crashing because it is using too much memory when it boots:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

You will need to use less than 512MB of RAM both at boot and at runtime. We do 
have this page https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues that 
provides some pointers for debugging memory issues.
```

So I've read the https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues document and I have several questions:

1) Is there an easy solution for this problem? (if you are a programmer, not interesting in administration of your machine).

2) Which program should I use to check how much memory I'm using: VisualVM?

3) What thing should I look for in order to reduce memory usage and not create a bigger problem?

Thanks

EDIT FROM HEROKU CUSTOMER SERVICE:

Java tends to be a little bit more memory hungry, but it should be obeying the JAVA_OPTS set. What happens when you just unset the JAVA_OPTS and rely on our defaults? You can unset it with heroku config:unset JAVA_OPTS -a jhipsterpress. I ask because typically we will automatically set JAVA_OPTS to something that should run correctly on the platform given available memory.

Comment: What are the jvm memory options you set for your app ?

Comment: Sorry Gael, I do not know. I'm completely lost. Where should I start? Where can I look at that? Thanks

Comment: The Jhipster heroku sub generator has generated a `Procfile` in your project folder and it uses `$JAVA_OPTS` which you can configure in your app dashboard in Config Vars section. So you could try to set JVM memory options like `-Xms` and `-Xmx`. Please note that I'm not a Heroku user. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt#configuring-java-options

Comment: I got some help from Heroku customer service, but it looks like it does not work. Thanks a lot, Gael